# Can someone tell me how to get the menu bar to show in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

First ever mac user, and the first thing I did was download Java 1.8 and Eclipse Photon for Java developers. Eclipse seems to be working but the file menu is gone. Google says the solution is to click on Window > Customized solution to get toolbar, but Window IS part of the toolbar.

I also can't seem to get snip to work or I'd include a visual, but one thing at a time.

Comment: The menu is at the top of the screen, in the same place as all OS X applications

Comment: I just realized what you were saying. Mac is weird. Thank you

Comment: No problem! glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, for a proper answer: all OS X applications display their menu in the same place at the top of the screen, and Eclipse is no exception. Here's how it looks, with the menu you're looking for highlighted in red:

[image]